# Ecto.Repo.update_all for atomic updates?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

There's a section in [Phoenix's Contexts guide](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/contexts.html#adding-cms-functions) that adds page-view-incrementing functionality to a dummy CMS context. The function that's created in the CMS context looks like this:

```
def inc_page_views(%Page{} = page) do
  {1, [%Page{views: views}]} =
    from(p in Page, where: p.id == ^page.id, select: [:views])
    |> Repo.update_all(inc: [views: 1])

  put_in(page.views, views)
end
```

Paraphrasing, `inc_page_views` takes a `Page` struct, uses its `id` to look up the corresponding database record, uses `Repo.update_all` to atomically increment the view count (see docs for an interleaving example), ensures that only 1 record was updated, and returns a new `Page` with the update view count.

Why does this example use [`Ecto.Repo.update_all/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:update_all/3) rather than [`Ecto.Repo.update/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:update/2)? Since we know we want to operate on only 1 record, it feels strange to potentially update a bunch of records and retroactively check that we didn't, rather than updating a specific `Ecto.Changeset`, which might look something like this:

```
def inc_page_views(%Page{views: curr_views} = page) do
  page
  |> Page.changeset(%{views: curr_views + 1})
  |> Repo.update()
end
```

This implementation is shorter/simpler, but I'm guessing the Phoenix doc writers didn't use it for a good reason. My hunch is that the `Repo.update` version must lack that atomic update property that's supposedly present in the `Repo.update_all` version, but I have no idea why! Can someone help explain the difference between these implementations and why the docs might have chosen the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def inc_page_views(%Page{views: curr_views} = page) do
  page
  |> Page.changeset(%{views: curr_views + 1})
  |> Repo.update()
end
```

it introduces a race condition. Imagine that you get the page from the database and it has `views` equal to 5. Then, while you are running the function above, the other db connection from the other process may change the value from 5 to 6. But since this function doesn't know about it, it will still add 1 to the 5 (now outdated value) and write to the database the value `6`.

As a result, instead of having the correct value 7, you have 6.

The way to prevent that is to use database locks doing something like that:

```
Page
|> where(id: ^id)
|> lock("FOR UPDATE")
|> Repo.one!()
|> inc_page_views()
```

Or simply use the `Repo.update_all` that makes sure that the operation is atomic.

Comment: That makes sense. You would need to at least lock that one record to avoid the race condition, and just issuing a `Repo.update()` doesn't do that. I'll need to read more into the Ecto docs!

Comment: For future me, `Repo.update`/`update!` take a `changeset`, while `update_all` takes a `queryable`. This means `update` is intrinsically linked to a *read, modify (changeset), write* pattern, while `update_all` is able to perform everything in one query (select-and-update). See also this [elixirforum thread](https://elixirforum.com/t/ecto-postgres-database-simultaneous-update/31848/2).